# php jQuery autocomplete not working fine in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, autocomplete

I've been working to add autocomplete to my Location text field, the problem is when I type any word on it, it always display all the result.

This is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#Location").autocomplete({
            source: "{{ route('search.autocomplete') }}",
            minLength: 3,
            select: function(event, ui){
                $("#Location").val(ui.item.value);
             }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is the route.php

```
Route::get('search/autocomplete', ['uses' => 'SearchController@autocomplete', 'as' => 'search.autocomplete']);
```

This is the searchController

```
public function autocomplete(Request $request){
        $term = $request->get('Location');

        $provinces = DB::table('provinces')->where('ProvinceName', 'LIKE', '%'. $term .'%')
        ->orderBy('ProvinceName', 'desc')
        ->get();

        $results = [];
        foreach ($provinces as $province) {
            $results[] = ['id' => $province->id, 'value' => $province->ProvinceName];
        }
        return response()->json($results);
}
```

and this is the search.blade.php

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
                Location: {!!Form::text('Location', Request::get('Location'), ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'What is your location?', 'id' => 'Location', 'style' => 'width: 250px;'])!!}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I solve my problem, I change

route.php

```
Route::get('search/autocomplete', 'SearchController@autocomplete');
```

SearchController

```
if ($request->ajax()) {
        $term = Input::get('term');

        $results = array();  

        $queries = DB::table('provinces')
            ->where('ProvinceName', 'LIKE', '%'.$term.'%')
            ->take(5)->get();

        foreach ($queries as $query)
        {
            $results[] = [ 'id' => $query->id, 'value' => $query->ProvinceName ];
        }
        return Response::json($results);
}
```

and my Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
         $( "#Location" ).autocomplete({
          source: "{{ url('search/autocomplete') }}",
          minLength: 3,
          select: function(event, ui) {
            $('#Location').val(ui.item.value);
          }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> An array of objects with label and value properties: [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]
>
> The label property is displayed in the suggestion menu. The value will be inserted into the input element when a user selects an item. If just one property is specified, it will be used for both, e.g., if you provide only value properties, the value will also be used as the label.

Change

```
$results[] = ['id' => $province->id, 'value' => $province->ProvinceName];
```

to

```
$results[] = ['value' => $province->id, 'label' => $province->ProvinceName];
```

And

```
$("#Location").val(ui.item.value);
```

To

```
$("#Location").val(ui.item.label);
```

Use id in frontend as

```
ui.item.value
```

Comment: nothing happens, it always returning all of my data in my database. It means that every time I type any words on my text field, it didn't matter.

Comment: [{"id":2,"value":"Test1"},{"id":1,"value":"Test2"}] 

this is my json return.